# Understand Heroku Memory using long-runtime-metrics

Tags: memory, logging, heroku

My logs:

```
2015-01-11T21:27:51.320958+00:00 heroku[web.2]: source=web.2 dyno=heroku.11366593.5e2ebae2-460b-481b-826a-22c41bd90695 sample#memory_total=268.89MB sample#memory_rss=268.88MB sample#memory_cache=0.01MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=74175pages sample#memory_pgpgout=5339pages
2015-01-11T21:27:52.194907+00:00 heroku[web.2]: source=web.2 dyno=heroku.11366593.471fa82a-4b2f-4819-946e-02635fe387c6 sample#memory_total=417.94MB sample#memory_rss=404.46MB sample#memory_cache=4.29MB sample#memory_swap=9.18MB sample#memory_pgpgin=747677pages sample#memory_pgpgout=643035pages
2015-01-11T21:28:07.011011+00:00 heroku[web.2]: source=web.2 dyno=heroku.11366593.82a95b43-b1d8-4fb7-9329-64fefb3bfe74 sample#memory_total=310.07MB sample#memory_rss=306.77MB sample#memory_cache=3.30MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=302671pages sample#memory_pgpgout=223294pages
2015-01-11T21:28:13.287206+00:00 heroku[web.2]: source=web.2 dyno=heroku.11366593.5e2ebae2-460b-481b-826a-22c41bd90695 sample#memory_total=268.93MB sample#memory_rss=268.92MB sample#memory_cache=0.01MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=74185pages sample#memory_pgpgout=5339pages
2015-01-11T21:28:29.199851+00:00 heroku[web.2]: source=web.2 dyno=heroku.11366593.82a95b43-b1d8-4fb7-9329-64fefb3bfe74 sample#memory_total=310.26MB sample#memory_rss=306.96MB sample#memory_cache=3.30MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=302720pages sample#memory_pgpgout=223294pages
2015-01-11T21:28:34.433135+00:00 heroku[web.2]: source=web.2 dyno=heroku.11366593.471fa82a-4b2f-4819-946e-02635fe387c6 sample#memory_total=417.95MB sample#memory_rss=404.48MB sample#memory_cache=4.29MB sample#memory_swap=9.18MB sample#memory_pgpgin=747681pages sample#memory_pgpgout=643035pages
2015-01-11T21:28:35.388654+00:00 heroku[web.2]: source=web.2 dyno=heroku.11366593.5e2ebae2-460b-481b-826a-22c41bd90695 sample#memory_total=268.93MB sample#memory_rss=268.92MB sample#memory_cache=0.01MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=74186pages sample#memory_pgpgout=5339pages
2015-01-11T21:28:51.260323+00:00 heroku[web.2]: source=web.2 dyno=heroku.11366593.82a95b43-b1d8-4fb7-9329-64fefb3bfe74 sample#memory_total=310.28MB sample#memory_rss=306.98MB sample#memory_cache=3.30MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=302726pages sample#memory_pgpgout=223294pages
2015-01-11T21:28:55.235542+00:00 heroku[web.2]: source=web.2 dyno=heroku.11366593.471fa82a-4b2f-4819-946e-02635fe387c6 sample#memory_total=417.95MB sample#memory_rss=404.48MB sample#memory_cache=4.29MB sample#memory_swap=9.18MB sample#memory_pgpgin=747681pages sample#memory_pgpgout=643035pages
```

Notice that `memory_total` jumps by huge amount within the space of 1 minute. How should I interpret and understand this?

Comment: Any luck with this? I am pulling my hair out with this as well. I deployed tonight and am experiencing the same issue.  I am very novice with Meteor and heroku, not much has changed in the app. This started happening with todays deploy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got three different dynos reporting with the name `web.2` - check the guids, `5e2ebae2-...`, `471fa82a-...`, and `82a95b43-...`.

If you examine the memory figures next to each, they're pretty much constant for each individual dyno: ie, you have no memory jumps.

Why you have three dynos with the same name is another matter. Maybe you've got preboot enabled? That starts new dynos up in the background, with the same name.

Comment: That's probably it. I had preboot enabled. I also probably had multiple puma worker processes per dyno. But I would guess those forks would be summed under their common dyno.